# Is there a way to find out who registered a certain appspot identifier?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to find out who registered a certain appspot (Google App Engine) identifier?

Please tell me if this belongs to another SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your comments, this might be helpful...

Google reserves appspot identifiers for all gmail accounts. So, if you own obscureidentifier@gmail.com, google is reserving it (obscureidentifier.appspot.com) for that account. All you need to do is login to appengine with that account in order to claim it.

Alternately, if you don't own the identifier@gmail.com, check to see if the account is registered by trying to register it. If it is, try emailing it. You never know. :)

FWIW, visiting the domain of a reserved identifier that hasn't been setup gives that error.

Comment: Yes, Google seems to reserve Gmail account handles as appspot handles. I didn't find any reference to that policy in the doc, though. Did you?

Comment: I remembered it from the O'Reilly book, *Programming Google App Engine*, p. 57. "Additionally, Google reserves every Gmail username as an application ID that only the corresponding Gmail user can register."

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your resolution? Do you own the Gmail account or does someone else?

Comment: Someone else does (I don't know who). I guess this is not a big deal really ;)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any way to do this.

Comment: while we're on the subject, will an identifier ever be recycled after I delete it?

Comment: @hyperslug Not currently, but it's not totally out of the question that it might be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://[identifier].appspot.com. With a bit of luck you'll find the authors contact address there. Otherwise I doubt Google will provide you that info.

Comment: I tried that, but only get: "Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Comment: anyway how important can be the identifier? You're likely to bind your own domain to appspot. Many mainstream webservices don't use their complete name for these sort of things.

Comment: Well, it's just strange, considering that the name's not that common, and no other service has that name.

Comment: @vemv, it will be visible if you're using SSL since domain names are not supported for that.